# salesforce1 user profile different on one/one.app vs. mobile client

Tags: salesforce1-app

Currently the user profile carousel navigation has three different items..

```
On a desktop running one/one.app viewing a user profile:
  carousel1:  chatter / follow user
  carousel2:  about user / edit / reset password/ freeze actions
  carousel3:  related lists / mobile cards

On a mobile device viewing a user profile:
  carousel1:  chatter / follow user
  carousel2:  followers / following / direct reports / files / groups
  carousel3:  about user
```

If one adds a visualforce page to a mobile card on the user profile it will display fine in the browser using one/one.app..  Yet when we view the user profile in the mobile salesforce1 application we do not see the visualforce page / mobile cards.  More over the componets displayed are different as shown above..

Why does the one/one.app differ from the mobile client?

How do we get a visualforce page embedded on a mobile card to display on a mobile client?

Why are we getting different behaviour on one/one.app vs. mobile client?

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Same question on the developer forum. [salesforce1 user profile different on one/one.app vs. mobile client](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000AcFJIA0)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the one/one.app differ from the mobile client?
>
> Why are we getting different behaviour on one/one.app vs. mobile
> client?

The one/one.app doesn't really simulate a mobile device. If you want to do that you have to use the one/one.app and additionally use the [Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/mobile-emulation) of Chrome. But there still will be some differences between one/one.app and the Salesforce1 App.

> How do we get a visualforce page embedded on a mobile card to display
> on a mobile client?

Do you ckeck the [Available for Salesforce mobile apps](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/spring14/release-notes/customize_sf1_visualforce.htm) Checkbox for the Visualforce pages you want to use for your mobile cards ?

Comment: Thank David.  Everything you say is true.. But sorry this still doesn't answer how we get visualforce pages in a mobile card on a native app in the user profile.  Yes the vfpage is available for salesforce mobile apps and does show up in one/one.app but not on mobile client.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce confirmed that this is the current behavior on ipad/iphone clients.  Was told this should be fixed with next release..